# How to stop the server from processing a request when it's aborted in the frontend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, http

I'm building a React app that communicates with an Expressjs server and a Flask api, the servers make extensive processes treating images and files so performance is top priority.

the desired outcome is stopping the processing of aborted requests, in React useEffect cleanups and elsewhere requests are aborted but the Expressjs API still proecsses them and returns data when it's not needed, is there any way to achieve something like that?

I tried using AbortController signals, and adding an "aborted" event in the api but it didn't work